# API to handle voice packets in Android

Tags: android, speech

Is there an API that deals with voice packets during a call in Android? How can I access voice packets?

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have access to the in-call audio via the Android SDK, sorry.

Comment: is there a non-android SDK way then to access the same?

Comment: @Sriram: I'm not even sure it is possible at the firmware level. As of 2009, the in-call audio wasn't even available to the Android OS -- it was handled by even lower level stuff driving the various chipsets.

Comment: I found this Manifest.Permission in the Android documentation: PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS and was wondering if there was any more documentation on what is meant by "monitor, modify or abort outgoing calls" or even if it could be used in this case.